# Change query on Mongoose stream

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a NodeJS server script with a bit of Socket.io, Express and Mongoose. Right now I have a stream query, the problem is that I want to change at some time the query.

Example:

```
var stream = Collection.find({date:{'$gt':currentTime}}).tailable().stream();
```

That works perfectly and send events to the: stream.on('data'); So that's cool.

But how I can change that query meanwhile is being streamed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Basically you're asking for a way to change the query an existing cursor is bound to and that's not possible.  You'd have to close your existing query stream and open a new one.